# ExactTarget won't let me define variable as subscriber's email address

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Here's my code. @email always comes up blank.

```
%%[
var @post_id, @url, @xml, @email, @query_vars, @query_vars2
set @post_id = Lookup("post_id","post_id","id",1)
@email = [Email Address]
@query_vars = Concat(@email,"&id=")
@query_vars2 = Concat(@query_vars, @post_id)
set @url = Concat("https://autoconnect.aaa.biz/feed?cat_user_email=", @query_vars2)
set @xml =  HTTPGet(v(@url))

Set @titles = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//item/title",1)
Set @descs = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//item/description",1)
Set @pubdas = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//item/pubDate",1)
Set @links = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//item/link",1)
SET @rowCount = 1

    for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

    IF RowCount(@titles) < 1 THEN
        RaiseError(@url, true)
    ENDIF

        Set @pubda = Field(Row(@pubdas,@i), "Value")

            Set @title = Field(Row(@titles,@i),"Value")
            Set @desc = Field(Row(@descs,@i), "Value")
            Set @link = Field(Row(@links,@i), "Value") 
            Set @pubda = Field(Row(@pubdas,@i), "Value") 
]%%
            <h1 style="Margin-top: 0;font-weight: normal;color: #447294;font-family: Georgia,serif;font-size: 26px;Margin-bottom: 12px;line-height: 36px">%%=v(@title)=%%</h1><p style="Margin-top: 0;font-weight: normal;color: #808285;font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 14px;Margin-bottom: 20px;line-height: 22px">%%=v(@desc)=%%...<a style="color: #4293b2;text-decoration: underline" data-emb-href-display="@%%=v(@link)=%%?utm_source=AutoConnect&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Alerts" href="%%=v(@link)=%%?utm_source=AutoConnect&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Weekly%20Digest" target="_blank">Read More</a></p>
%%[ 
    next @i  
]%%
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See comments in the code below:

```
%%[
var @post_id, @url, @xml, @email, @query_vars, @query_vars2

set @post_id = Lookup("post_id","post_id","id",1)

/* missing 'set' on the next 3 lines */
/* your sending list or DE must include the Email Address attribute/column */
set @email = [Email Address]

/* don't need these (see below) */
/* set @query_vars = Concat(@email,"&id=") */
/* set @query_vars2 = Concat(@query_vars, @post_id) */

/* you can concat as many strings together as you need*/
set @url = Concat("https://autoconnect.aaa.biz/feed?cat_user_email=", @email,"&id=",@post_id)

/* don't need the v() function on this */
/* set @xml =  HTTPGet(v(@url)) */
set @xml =  HTTPGet(@url)

Set @titles = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//item/title",1)
Set @descs = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//item/description",1)
Set @pubdas = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//item/pubDate",1)
Set @links = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//item/link",1)

/* not sure what this is accomplishing: */
/* SET @rowCount = 1 */

/* seems like it should be this: */
Set @rowCount = rowcount(@titles)

/* this should be outside of your for loop */
IF @rowCount < 1 THEN
    RaiseError(@url, true)
endif

for @i = 1 to @rowCount do
    Set @pubda = Field(Row(@pubdas,@i), "Value")
    Set @title = Field(Row(@titles,@i),"Value")
    Set @desc = Field(Row(@descs,@i), "Value")
    Set @link = Field(Row(@links,@i), "Value") 
    Set @pubda = Field(Row(@pubdas,@i), "Value") 
]%%
    <h1 style="Margin-top: 0;font-weight: normal;color: #447294;font-family: Georgia,serif;font-size: 26px;Margin-bottom: 12px;line-height: 36px">%%=v(@title)=%%</h1>
    <p style="Margin-top: 0;font-weight: normal;color: #808285;font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 14px;Margin-bottom: 20px;line-height: 22px">%%=v(@desc)=%%...
       <a style="color: #4293b2;text-decoration: underline" data-emb-href-display="@%%=v(@link)=%%?utm_source=AutoConnect&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Alerts" href="%%=v(@link)=%%?utm_source=AutoConnect&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Weekly%20Digest" target="_blank">Read More</a>
    </p>
%%[ 
next @i  
]%%
```

Comment: Wow, there was a lot wrong with that! Thanks so much. I've been trying to get this for days!